# Output shapefile for the igraph network in R

Tags: r, spatial, arcgis, igraph

Hello I have a network in R using the igraph library

```
Vertices: 616 
Edges: 6270 
Directed: TRUE 
No graph attributes.
Vertex attributes: name, Lat, Lon.
Edge attributes: V3.
```

How can I generate two shapefiles for the Vertices and the Edges using the Lat, Lon info in the vertex?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using the `sp` and `maptools` packages.  There are handy functions `writePointsShape()` and `writeLinesShape()` in `maptools` that will write to the ESRI shapefile format.

Before doing this, it is necessary to extract the lat/lon information from the graph vertices and put it into a `SpatialPoints` object for the vertices, and a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` object for the edges.

This code produces a very simple `igraph` object for the following example:

```
library(igraph)

## Produce a ring graph with 4 vertices
x <- graph.ring(4)

## Add lat/lon information to vertices
V(x)$lat <- c(50, 50, 51, 51)
V(x)$lon <- c(40, 41, 41, 40)
```

Now, create the `SpatialPoints` object for the vertices

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)

## Create SpatialPoints object containing coordinates
xV <- SpatialPoints(cbind(V(x)$lon, V(x)$lat))

## Write vertices to a shapefile
writePointsShape(xV, fn="vertices")
```

Finally, create the `SpatialLinesDataFrame` object for the edges.  This is a little messy, but I am yet to find a quick way to produce a SpatialLines object given coordinates.

```
## Create SpatialLinesDataFrame object describing edges
edges <- get.edgelist(x)+1
edges <- cbind(edgeNum=1:nrow(edges), v1=edges[,1], v2=edges[,2])
xE <- apply(edges, 1, function(i) Lines(Line(cbind(c(V(x)$lon[i["v1"]], V(x)$lon[i["v2"]]), c(V(x)$lat[i["v1"]], V(x)$lat[i["v2"]]))), ID=as.character(i["edgeNum"])))
xE <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(SpatialLines(xE), data=data.frame(edgeNum=1:nrow(edges)))

## Write edges to a shapefile
writeLinesShape(xE, fn="edges")
```

Comment: Had transposed Lat and Lon.  Corrected now.  Repeat after me:  (Lon=X, Lat=Y) :)

Comment: Error in validityMethod(object) : coords cannot contain missing values. That is how I get for the "apply" function for the line. Do you have any suggestions that I can check the values. Sorry I am a new hand in R...

Comment: I am assuming that you are running this on your 616 vertex network, not the example 4 vertex ring given.  Sounds like there are some vertices that don't have lat/lon information.  You can check using `print(yourGraph, vertex=T)`

Comment: Finally I made it work! Thanks! The last question remaining is to distinguish the directions of the edges of the graph....

Comment: Not sure how you would represent a directed edge (i.e. arc) in a shapefile.  Are arcs/arrows part of the ESRI shapefile specification?