# shapefile to neural network in R

Tags: r, networking, nodes, shapefile, edges

I need to convert a shapefile (ESRI) of roads type `SpatialLinesDataFrame` in a neural network in R.

I do not know how to remove nodes or vertices of the shape. Determine the length of each edge between nodes. With these parameters I can create the network using the packet (network).

Summary: Input shapefile for the igraph network in R.

Thank you from the South of Chile.

Comment: I think we could improve the wording here, but it is a reasonable question with a bit of work. Looks like one uber user says no

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps if you made a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your question / problem, people would find it easier to answer.

Comment: Agreed on reopen. My guess is "I have a LINE shapefile of connected segments and I want to turn it into a graph network so I can load it into an igraph package object and do shortest-path routing etc on it". The answer then involves building topology from lines and is not trivial...

Comment: We have reopened the question to give you a chance to provide some more information. Please describe your input data in more detail, e.g. by providing the results of `str(x)` or `head(x)`.

Comment: it seems like the inverse of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205227/output-shapefile-for-the-igraph-network-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try --

```
library(rgdal)
library(igraph)

dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
sl <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="kiritimati_primary_roads")
lines2xcoord <- function(lns) sapply(lns@Lines, function(l) l@coords[,1])
lines2ycoord <- function(lns) sapply(lns@Lines, function(l) l@coords[,2])

x <- unlist(sapply(sl@lines, lines2xcoord))
y <- unlist(sapply(sl@lines, lines2ycoord))

g <- graph.empty(n=length(x), directed=FALSE)
V(g)$lat <- x
V(g)$lng <- y
e <- c(t(matrix(c(head(V(g),-1),tail(V(g),-1)), ncol=2)))
add.edges(g,e)
```

Now `g` is an igraph with the lines. It assumes incorrectly the lines in the shapefile to be connected, though. Also, it does not store lat/lon in this example, but the projected coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The [shp2graph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shp2graph/shp2graph.pdf) package can convert `SpatialLinesDataFrame` objects into igraph objects. Have a look at the `nel2igraph` function. Here is an example taken from the help file:

```
data(ORN)
rtNEL<-readshpnw(rn, ELComputed=TRUE)
#Add the edge length as the weight for graph
igr<-nel2igraph(rtNEL[[2]],rtNEL[[3]],weight=rtNEL[[4]])
plot(igr, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=2,vertex.size2=2)
#plot(rn)
```

`rn` is a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` object that is first converted into a list object, and then converted into an igraph object.