# creating road network datasets in R

Tags: r, gis, spatial

I have a line shapefile containing roads, and I'd like to use it to create a network dataset. In ArcGIS, I'd do this with the Network Analyst extension (see [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_network_dataset/004700000007000000/)).

Is there an R package with the equivalent functionality? I've checked out [Bivand's Cran Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) for the analysis of spatial data, and I've searched a bit on SO and the [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/alternatives-to-network-analyst), but I haven't found any good leads. I've also looked through Bivand et al.'s (2013) [Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DJ8H3V4).

I've been using R for a while, but not for spatial data processing and analysis. I'd appreciate any package suggestions or tips about other resources.

Comment: It would help if you posted a link to a sample road file, and some simple task that you want to do with it. Also, check out this [example of converting a road shapefile to an graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943208/shapefile-to-neural-network-in-r).

Comment: here is [a simple example](https://github.com/ericpgreen/SO/tree/master/spatial-weights). i'd like to create a matrix of shortest distances between points using the road network.

Comment: @EricGreen Your link is broken?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `shp2graph` package. It allows to input a `SpatialLines` or `SpatialLinesDataFrame` (ie. a lines shapefile loaded through the `readShapeLines` function in the `maptools` library) to create a network. And then through the function `points2network` integrate a points data set into an existing network. For example, these points could be the coordinates of city centroids. Then, through the `igraph` package you could analyze the network.