# How to Use "tbl_graphs" in R?

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

**Based on a shapefile, I am trying to visualize/find out the driving distance between two coordinates (e.g. CN Tower and Toronto Pearson Airport).**

First I loaded the shapefile:

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(sfnetworks)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygraph)

# Set the URL for the shapefile
url <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/RNF-FRR/files-fichiers/lrnf000r22a_e.zip"

# Create a temporary folder to download and extract the shapefile
temp_dir <- tempdir()
temp_file <- file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.zip")

# Download the shapefile to the temporary folder
download.file(url, temp_file)

# Extract the shapefile from the downloaded zip file
unzip(temp_file, exdir = temp_dir)

# Read the shapefile using the rgdal package
# source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456748/strategies-for-working-with-large-shapefiles/456798#456798
a = st_read(file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.shp"), query="select * from lrnf000r22a_e where PRUID_R ='35'")
```

The shapefile looks something like this:

```
Simple feature collection with 570706 features and 21 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5963148 ymin: 665490.8 xmax: 7581671 ymax: 2212179
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert
First 10 features:
   OBJECTID NGD_UID       NAME TYPE  DIR AFL_VAL ATL_VAL AFR_VAL ATR_VAL CSDUID_L                           CSDNAME_L CSDTYPE_L CSDUID_R                           CSDNAME_R CSDTYPE_R PRUID_L PRNAME_L PRUID_R PRNAME_R RANK
1         4 3434819       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3526003                           Fort Erie         T  3526003                           Fort Erie         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
2         5 1358252      South LINE <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3551027                Gordon/Barrie Island        MU  3551027                Gordon/Barrie Island        MU      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
3         8 1778927       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3512054                           Wollaston        TP  3512054                           Wollaston        TP      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
4        11  731932     Albion   RD <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    2010    2010  3520005                             Toronto         C  3520005                             Toronto         C      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    3
5        18 3123617  County 41   RD <NA>     640     708     635     709  3511015                     Greater Napanee         T  3511015                     Greater Napanee         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    3
6        20 4814160       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3553005     Greater Sudbury / Grand Sudbury        CV  3553005     Greater Sudbury / Grand Sudbury        CV      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
7        21 1817031       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3537028                         Amherstburg         T  3537028                         Amherstburg         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
8        24 4825761       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3554094 Timiskaming, Unorganized, West Part        NO  3554094 Timiskaming, Unorganized, West Part        NO      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
9        25  544891     Dunelm   DR <NA>       1       9       2      10  3526053                      St. Catharines        CY  3526053                      St. Catharines        CY      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
10       28 1835384 Seven Oaks   DR <NA>     730     974     731     975  3515005             Otonabee-South Monaghan        TP  3515005             Otonabee-South Monaghan        TP      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
   CLASS                 _ogr_geometry_
1     23 LINESTRING (7269806 859183,...
2     23 LINESTRING (6921247 1133452...
3     23 LINESTRING (7320857 1089403..
```

Then I tried to calculate the distance by treating the road network as a graph:

```
# Convert the shapefile to an sfnetwork object
net <- as_sfnetwork(a)

# Define the two points of interest in WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
pt1 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.68312))
pt2 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.64256))

# Set the CRS of the points to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
pt1 <- st_sfc(pt1, crs = 4326)
pt2 <- st_sfc(pt2, crs = 4326)

# Transform the points to the CRS of the network
pt1_transformed <- st_transform(pt1, st_crs(net))
pt2_transformed <- st_transform(pt2, st_crs(net))

# Find the nearest points on the network to the transformed points of interest
n1 <- st_nearest_feature(pt1_transformed, net)
n2 <- st_nearest_feature(pt2_transformed, net)
```

From here, I create a "tbl_graph":

```
path <- net %>%
    activate(edges) %>%
    mutate(weight = edge_length()) %>%
    as_tbl_graph()

> path
# A tbl_graph: 430824 nodes and 570706 edges
#
# A directed multigraph with 442 components
#
# Edge Data: 570,706 x 25 (active)
   from    to OBJECTID NGD_UID NAME      TYPE  DIR   AFL_VAL ATL_VAL AFR_VAL ATR_VAL CSDUID_L CSDNAME_L   CSDTYPE~ CSDUID~ CSDNAME_R  CSDTYP~ PRUID_L PRNAME~ PRUID_R PRNAME~ RANK  CLASS                  `_ogr_geometry_` weight
  <int> <int>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>       <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>                  <LINESTRING [m]>    [m]
1     1     2        4 3434819 NA        NA    NA    NA      NA      NA      NA      3526003  Fort Erie   T        3526003 Fort Erie  T       35      Ontario 35      Ontario 5     23    (7269806 859183, 7269795 859166.~   25.9
2     3     4        5 1358252 South     LINE  NA    NA      NA      NA      NA      3551027  Gordon/Bar~ MU       3551027 Gordon/Ba~ MU      35      Ontario 35      Ontario 5     23    (6921247 1133452, 6921258 113345~ 1245. 
3     5     6        8 1778927 NA        NA    NA    NA      NA      NA      NA      3512054  Wollaston   TP       3512054 Wollaston  TP      35      Ontario 35      Ontario 5     23    (7320857 1089403, 7320903 108942~  254. 
4     7     8       11 731932  Albion    RD    NA    NA      NA      2010    2010    3520005  Toronto     C        3520005 Toronto    C       35      Ontario 35      Ontario 3     21    (7202555 935281.3, 7202653 93533~  111. 
5     9    10       18 3123617 County 41 RD    NA    640     708     635     709     3511015  Greater Na~ T        3511015 Greater N~ T       35      Ontario 35      Ontario 3     21    (7403627 1039328, 7403431 103963~  367. 
6    11    12       20 4814160 NA        NA    NA    NA      NA      NA      NA      3553005  Greater Su~ CV       3553005 Greater S~ CV      35      Ontario 35      Ontario 5     21    (7042806 1222708, 7042838 122273~  191. 
# ... with 570,700 more rows
#
# Node Data: 430,824 x 1
    `_ogr_geometry_`
         <POINT [m]>
1   (7269806 859183)
2 (7269790 859162.7)
3  (6921247 1133452)
# ... with 430,821 more rows
```

**My Question:** From here, I am not sure how to use the tbl_graph to find the distance between the two points n1 and n2:

```
> n1
[1] 110393
> n2
[1] 319271
```

I think n1 and n2 correspond to the "to" and "from" columns in the "path" tbl_graph - but I am not sure how to use the tbl_graph to find out the distance between n1 and n2.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n1` & `n2` are indeces, row numbers of one of the `net` tibbles.  Those values can be used to subset graph lists or used as `from` and `to` parameters for `igraph::shortest_paths()`. In this case, `n1` & `n2` probably targeted edges tibble as nodes were not activated first. Means that if you used those `n1` & `n2` for finding shortest path, you probably witnessed some rather funky results. Or perhaps just an empty list.

Also, the `sfnetworks` object, `net`, inherits from `tbl_graph` and also `igraph`,  so `tiynetworks` and `igraph` methods should work just fine on `net`without converting it first. `net` -> `path` conversion, while adding weights, leads no closer to desired route. It's still (almost) the same `tbl_graph` it was before, now without a spatial layer.  `sfnetworks` also implements all what's needed for your main objective: `st_network_paths()` and/or  `to_spatial_shortest_paths()` morpher.

`sfnetwork` was also configured to be directed (well, it's a default setting), this most likely will ruin all routing attempts, at least in this case.

##### `sfnetworks::st_network_paths()` approach

```r
library(sf)
library(sfnetworks)
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

shp_url <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/RNF-FRR/files-fichiers/lrnf000r22a_e.zip"
if (!file.exists(basename(shp_url))) curl::curl_download(shp_url, basename(shp_url), quiet = FALSE)            

# keep archive zipped; 
# predefined bbox, small patch in Toronto, 
# covers cover both points and leaves plenty of routing options
a <- read_sf(paste0("/vsizip/", basename(shp_url)), 
             wkt_filter = "POLYGON ((7200615 918857, 7211499 918857, 7211499 933387, 7200615 933387, 7200615 918857))")
a
#> Simple feature collection with 7584 features and 21 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 7199959 ymin: 918285.7 xmax: 7211930 ymax: 934030.6
#> Projected CRS: NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert
#> # A tibble: 7,584 × 22
#>    OBJECTID NGD_UID NAME    TYPE  DIR   AFL_VAL ATL_VAL AFR_VAL ATR_VAL CSDUID_L
#>       <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   
#>  1      668 4668376 Dixie   RD    <NA>  2520    2520    2531    2543    3521005 
#>  2      874 4617171 401     HWY   <NA>  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    3521005 
#>  3     2252 4092570 Breton  AVE   <NA>  178     300     175     295     3521005 
#>  4     3320 485941  Kipling AVE   <NA>  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    3520005 
#>  5     3698 4775771 Eringa… DR    <NA>  99      105     108     120     3520005 
#>  6     3700 507598  Bristol RD    W     <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    3521005 
#>  7     4472 4683515 Airport RD    <NA>  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    3521005 
#>  8     4759 5779033 401     HWY   <NA>  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    3520005 
#>  9     5051 505570  Grand … RD    <NA>  3496    3530    3511    3525    3521005 
#> 10     5533 5876974 Yorkda… CRES  <NA>  31      67      30      58      3520005 
#> # ℹ 7,574 more rows
#> # ℹ 12 more variables: CSDNAME_L <chr>, CSDTYPE_L <chr>, CSDUID_R <chr>,
#> #   CSDNAME_R <chr>, CSDTYPE_R <chr>, PRUID_L <chr>, PRNAME_L <chr>,
#> #   PRUID_R <chr>, PRNAME_R <chr>, RANK <chr>, CLASS <chr>,
#> #   geometry <LINESTRING [m]>

# from / to points for routing:
pts <- tribble(~point,      ~lon,     ~lat,
                "pt1", -79.61203, 43.68312,
                "pt2", -79.61203, 43.64256) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords =c("lon", "lat"), crs = st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(a)) 

# create un-directed network (default is directed), 
# store edge lenghts as weights
net <- as_sfnetwork(a, directed = FALSE) %>%
  activate("edges") %>%
  mutate(weight = edge_length())

# get paths between pt1 & pt2 with sfnetwork
paths_sfn <- st_network_paths(net, 
                              from = pts[pts$point == "pt1", ], 
                              to =   pts[pts$point == "pt2", ], 
                              weights = "weight")
paths_sfn
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   node_paths edge_paths
#>   <list>     <list>    
#> 1 <int [54]> <int [53]>

# includes list of edge indeces that form the path:
paths_sfn$edge_paths[[1]]
#>  [1] 1027 1032 1295  697  121 2704 2702 2778 1125 1280 4364 1360  235 1686 2048
#> [16] 6115 2266  865 2508 7511 7179 2956 1823 5139 1055 5929 3684 3417 5960 1196
#> [31] 3383 1603 1975 1159 6250 5814   58 1964 3593 4423 3477 4940  383 5784 2362
#> [46] 4120 7251 1970 4834 5155  624 1935 5134

# get edges with matching indeces:
route <- net %>% 
  activate("edges") %>% 
  slice(paths_sfn$edge_paths[[1]]) %>% 
  st_as_sf()

# distance:
sum(route$weight)
#> 7505.43 [m]

# visualize
mapview(list(pts, route))
```

[image]

##### Path-finding and distance with `igraph`, using the same `net` object

```r
library(igraph)

# to find node indeces, keep net nodes activated
net <- net %>% activate("nodes")
n1 <- st_nearest_feature(pts[1,], net)
n2 <- st_nearest_feature(pts[2,], net)
node1; node2
#> [1] 1560
#> [1] 3938

# locate those on a map:
net %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  slice(c(n1, n2)) %>% 
  mapview(layer.name = "net nodes") +
  mapview(pts)
```

[image]

```r
# as sfnetwork inherits from tbl_graph and igraph:
class(net)
#> [1] "sfnetwork" "tbl_graph" "igraph"

# we can use igraph::shortest_paths() with our sfnetwork object:
paths_ig <- shortest_paths(net, n1, n2, output = "epath")

# paths_ig$epath is a list of edges:
str(paths_ig)
#> List of 4
#>  $ vpath        : NULL
#>  $ epath        :List of 1
#>   ..$ : 'igraph.es' int [1:53] 1027 1032 1295 697 121 2704 2702 2778 1125 1280 ...
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "aac7eae8-1b4f-11ee-a8b6-53eec7eb8cd4"
#>  $ predecessors : NULL
#>  $ inbound_edges: NULL

# when converted to integer, we'll have the same index list as 
# from sfnetwork::st_network_paths() :
e <- paths_ig$epath[[1]] %>% as.integer()

# check if those are indeed identical:
identical(e, paths_sfn$edge_paths[[1]])
#> [1] TRUE

# sum edge wights to get path distance:
sum(E(net)[e]$weight)
#> 7505.43 [m]

# we have not altered our original sf object (a) nor 
# sfnetwork object (net), so indeces should still match and we can use
# e for subsetting: a[e,]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = a, color = "grey80") +
  geom_sf(data = a[e,], linewidth = 1.5, alpha = .6) +
  geom_sf(data = pts, aes(color = point), size = 3) +
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(a), ylim = c(922000, 930000)) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

##### Morphers by `tidygraph` and `sfnetworks`

There are also morphers, i.e. `tidygraph::to_shortest_path` (would work with previous `n1` and `n2` objects for `from`/ `to`) and `sfnetworks::to_spatial_shortest_paths` (takes `sf` points for `from` / `to`, just like `st_network_paths()`) , so there's no need to worry about picking relevant nodes / edges from the network, `convert()` output is already filtered:

```r
library(tidygraph)

converted_net <-  net %>% convert(to_spatial_shortest_paths, pts[1,], pts[2,])
route_edges <- st_as_sf(converted_net, "edges")
route_nodes <- st_as_sf(converted_net, "nodes")

# route length:
sum(route_edges$weight)
#> 7505.43 [m]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = a, color = "grey80") +
  geom_sf(data = route_edges) +
  geom_sf(data = route_nodes, alpha  = .2) +
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(a), ylim = c(922000, 930000)) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @margsul: thank you so much for your wonderful answer! I am working on a related question here - can you please take a look at it if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77109335/r-visualizing-osm-data thank you so much!