# R: Visualizing OSM data

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

**I am trying to visualize the driving distance (i.e. road network) between the CN Tower and the Toronto Airport using OSM (Open Street Maps) in R.**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(osm)
library(osmdata)


pt1 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.68312))
pt2 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.64256))


pts <- st_sfc(pt1, pt2, crs = 4326)


bbox <- st_bbox(pts)


osm_highways <- opq(bbox = bbox) %>% 
    add_osm_feature(key = 'highway') %>% 
    osmdata_sf()


osm_buildings <- opq(bbox = bbox) %>% 
    add_osm_feature(key = 'building') %>% 
    osmdata_sf()


ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = osm_highways$osm_lines) +
    geom_sf(data = osm_buildings$osm_polygons, fill = "gray50") +
    geom_sf(data = pts, color = "red", size = 3)
```

[image]

**My Question:** When compared to other references (e.g. see below), the map I created looks a bit "empty" - and I am not sure how to trace the actual path between the two red dots.

After doing some reading, I thought that this is happening because maybe I did not add enough "features" when making the OSM call:

```
osm_roads <- opq(bbox = bbox) %>% 
    add_osm_feature(key = 'highway', value = c("motorway", "primary", "secondary")) %>% 
    osmdata_sf()
```

But this still did not work.

**Can someone please show me what I can do to make this map more detailed (e.g. add more roads, streets, etc.) and how to connect the road path between the two red points?**

Thanks!

**References:**

- [How to Use "tbl_graphs" in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76508074/13203841)
- https://taraskaduk.com/posts/2021-01-18-print-street-maps/
- https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c27b/93150bbbd85e682cbbd4529e662617361900.pdf
- https://jcoliver.github.io/learn-r/017-open-street-map.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4W_ey9sHlY

**Update:** After continuing to work on this problem, I made a bit of progress:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(osm)
library(osmdata)

pt1 <- st_point(c(-79.41203, 43.64312))  # CN Tower
pt2 <- st_point(c(-79.62683, 43.67772))  # Toronto Airport


pts <- st_sfc(pt1, pt2, crs = 4326)


bbox <- st_bbox(pts)


osm_features <- c("motorway", "trunk", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "residential", "path", "waterway", "natural")


osm_data <- opq(bbox = bbox) %>%
    add_osm_feature(key = 'highway', value = osm_features) %>%
    osmdata_sf()


ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = osm_data$osm_lines, color = "gray40") +
    geom_sf(data = osm_data$osm_polygons, fill = "lightblue") +  # Water bodies in light blue
    geom_sf(data = pts, color = "red", size = 3) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(bbox$xmin, bbox$xmax), ylim = c(bbox$ymin, bbox$ymax)) +
    theme_minimal()
```

**But the map still does not look correct? Is it possible to trace the path as well?**

[image]

Comment: Solved here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/467001/tracing-a-route-on-a-map

Answer (score 1):

if you need network analysis, first you need to build a graph item with topology. Vector (shp) data alone is not enough. You need to combine networkX or igraph package. Once you have built the topological network object (using igraph, for example), you can use functions such as shortest_path to do the analysis and visualization you need.

I believe this tutorial is exactly what you need. There are very detailed cases to explain, I hope to help you.
https://r-spatial.org/r/2019/09/26/spatial-networks.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).